# PHP convert multiple array-values to time format

Tags: php, arrays, time, time-format

For a project, i need to convert multiple values form an array to a time format in PHP. I've got arrays like this:
`starttime = ['year' => 2019, 'month' => 5, 'day' => 10, 'hour' => 20, 'minute' => 15]`
Is there a way to convert these values to a time format with which i can also calculate stuff? I already tried using strtotime, but it dind't work. 
Thanks for your answers!

Comment: By time format do you mean unix timestamp?

Comment: Do you mean something like this ? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1cfe4c3877a9a5ef42975827091a2a758c3daeba

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the `DateTime` object which has the [`setDate`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.setdate.php), [`setTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php) and [`getTimestamp`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php) methods. Which you can use for defining the date and time from the array keys, and retrieve the unix timestamp as a result.

### Example: https://3v4l.org/o3lVr

```
$starttime = ['year' => 2019, 'month' => 5, 'day' => 10, 'hour' => 20, 'minute' => 15];
$date = new \DateTime();
$date->setDate($starttime['year'], $starttime['month'], $starttime['day']);
$date->setTime($starttime['hour'], $starttime['minute']);

var_dump($timestamp = $date->getTimestamp());
var_dump(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp));
```

Results:

```
int(1557512100)
string(19) "2019-05-10 20:15:00"
```

---

Optionally to prevent issues with missing keys, in PHP >= 7.0 you can use the [null coalesce operator `??`](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) to default the values to the current date.

Example: https://3v4l.org/0MOI5

```
$starttime = ['month' => 5, 'day' => 10, 'minute' => 15];

$date = new \DateTime();
$date->setDate($starttime['year'] ?? $date->format('Y'), $starttime['month'] ?? $date->format('m'), $starttime['day'] ?? $date->format('d'));
$date->setTime($starttime['hour'] ?? $date->format('H'), $starttime['minute'] ?? $date->format('i'));

var_dump($timestamp = $date->getTimestamp());
var_dump(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp));
```

Results:

```
int(1557497700)
string(19) "2019-05-10 16:15:00"
```

---

Alternatively you can also use [`mktime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) to produce the same result. Please note, as per the manual, in PHP < 5.1.0 this method may produce unexpected (but not incorrect) results if `DST` is not specified.

Example: https://3v4l.org/DU0Q1

```
$starttime = ['year' => 2019, 'month' => 5, 'day' => 10, 'hour' => 20, 'minute' => 15];

$timestamp = mktime(
    $starttime['hour'], 
    $starttime['minute'], 
    0, 
    $starttime['month'], 
    $starttime['day'], 
    $starttime['year']
);

var_dump($timestamp);
var_dump(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp));
```

Results:

```
int(1557512100)
string(19) "2019-05-10 20:15:00"
```